# SX300 Expansion Board and SATA devices

Tags: hardware

I recently came across this 'module' and I have been wondering if it can be used to have a HDD plugged in into a raspberry. Does anyone know if an additional power supply is required in order to get the HDD working? and is there a huge performance difference against using the conventional SATA to USB way to connect a HDD?

Comment: Unclear what is being asked: far too little information is given about the module in question to reliably determine which of the many devices in the world the question is actually about.